# ODI Mapping to SQLCL

Tags: sqlclr, oracle-data-integrator

Could you help me ,how to convert the ODI Mapping into SQL CL?

Below steps need to convert:

1. copy file
2. ODI Mapping (file to table)
3. ODI Mapping (Table to table)